# Haskell: Is there a way to deduce the return type of a function from inside the function?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, return-value

Suppose I've got the following function:

```
import Data.Typeable
import Text.Read (reads)

parse :: (Read b, Typeable b) => String -> IO b
parse msg = case reads msg of
        [(value,"")] -> return value
        _ -> throwIO $ ErrorCall ("could not parse " ++ msg)
```

It parses a String into whatever I want it to.
If the String is malformed it throws an exception showing the message, that failed to parse.

I use this function in a do block of the IO-Monad like

```
(a,b) <- parse msg :: IO (Int,Int)
```

and at another place like

```
s <- parse msg :: IO String
```

Now, if I want to to make the exception more verbose reporting which type it failed to read

```
import Data.Typeable
import Text.Read (reads)

parse :: (Read b, Typeable b) => String -> IO b
parse msg = case reads msg of
        [(value,"")] -> return value
        _ -> throwIO $ ErrorCall ("could not parse " ++ msg ++ " as " ++
                         show ( typeOf something_that_has_type_b))
```

how do I get something, that has type b?

A possible workaround would be doing this

```
import Data.Typeable
import Text.Read (reads)

parse :: (Read b, Typeable b) => b -> String -> IO b
parse dummy msg = case reads msg of
        [(value,"")] -> return value
        _ -> throwIO $ ErrorCall ("could not parse " ++ msg ++ " as " ++
                         show ( typeOf dummy))
```

and invoking it like

```
s <- parse "" msg :: IO String
```

But that looks quite silly.

Is there a way to deduce the return type of a function from inside the function?

Comment: Additionally: What if you want to *return* values of a specific type when requested, and an error if an unhandled return type is requested?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need dummy variable, you can use `ScopedTypeVariables` extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

parse :: forall b. (Read b, Typeable b) => String -> IO b
parse msg = case reads msg of
    [(value,"")] -> return value
    _ -> error $ "could not parse " ++ msg ++ " as " ++
                     show (typeOf (undefined :: b))
```

Comment: It seems these days all the cool kids are using `Proxy` instead of `undefined` for this sort of thing.

Comment: @dfeuer Yep, that is correct. It is shame to use `undefined` when `Proxy` is in `base` now.

Comment: Yes, the modern way is `show (typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy b))`.

Comment: And even more modern (not merged into ghc yet) is `show (typeRep (:: b))`.

Comment: @augustss: That passes "modern" and well into "avant-garde" ;). Looks awesome though.

Comment: @augustss: when will it be merged? In GHC 8?